# Why is icc generating weird assembly for a simple main?

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, code-generation, icc

I have a simple [program](https://godbolt.org/z/3KD2CM):

```
int main()
{
    return 2*7;
}
```

both GCC and clang with optimizations turned on hapily generate 2 instruction binary, but icc gives bizarre output.

```
     push      rbp                                           #2.1
     mov       rbp, rsp                                      #2.1
     and       rsp, -128                                     #2.1
     sub       rsp, 128                                      #2.1
     xor       esi, esi                                      #2.1
     mov       edi, 3                                        #2.1
     call      __intel_new_feature_proc_init                 #2.1
     stmxcsr   DWORD PTR [rsp]                               #2.1
     mov       eax, 14                                       #3.12
     or        DWORD PTR [rsp], 32832                        #2.1
     ldmxcsr   DWORD PTR [rsp]                               #2.1
     mov       rsp, rbp                                      #3.12
     pop       rbp                                           #3.12
     ret
```

Comment: and if you change name of function to say `main2` (or any another) the code will changed - became usual. this mean that `main` is special name for icc compiler and it generate additional special code here

Comment: ICC is likely generating template code for `main` as part of a hosted environment that doesn't get optimized out. Rename`main` to something else or try using `-ffreestanding`. `main` gets special treatment.

Comment: Thank you. If any of you two want to make your comment into an A and explain why icc treats main differently I will accept the A.

Comment: @OrenIshShalom: The question is about a C++ program.  The Godbolt link shows that that source is being compiled as C++, not C.  ICC would emit the same asm for this as a C program (e.g. pass `-xc`), but arbitrarily changing the tag to C isn't appropriate.  My answer already mentions the C++ standard's rules for the program calling `main`.  (ISO C has the same rule, but you didn't edit my answer to match your change to the question.)

Comment: @OrenIsh: the rest of your edit was good, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know why ICC chooses to align the stack by 2 cache lines:

```
and       rsp, -128                                     #2.1
sub       rsp, 128                                      #2.1
```

That's interesting.  L2 cache has an adjacent-line prefetcher that likes to pull pairs of lines (in a 128-byte aligned group) into L2.  But main's stack frame is not usually heavily used.  Maybe important variables are allocated there in some programs.  (This also explains setting up `rbp`, to save the old RSP so it can return after ANDing.  gcc makes stack frames with RBP in functions where it aligns that stack, too.)

---

**The rest is because `main()` is special, and ICC enables `-ffast-math` by default**.  (This is one of Intel's "dirty" little secrets, and lets it auto-vectorize more floating-point code out of the box.)

This includes adding code to the top of `main` to set the DAZ / FTZ bits in the MXCSR (SSE status / control register). See Intel's x86 manuals for more about these bits, but they're really not complicated:

- DAZ: Denormals Are Zero: as inputs to an SSE/AVX instruction, denormals are treated as zero.
- FTZ: Flush To Zero: When rounding the *result* of an SSE/AVX instruction, subnormal results are flushed to zero.

related: [SSE "denormals are zeros" option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37886551/sse-denormals-are-zeros-option)

(**ISO C++ forbids a program from calling back into `main()`, so compilers are allowed to put run-once stuff in `main` itself instead of in CRT startup files**.  gcc/clang with `-ffast-math` specified for linking link in CRT startup files that set the MXCSR. But when compiling with gcc/clang, it only affects code-gen in terms of which optimizations are allowed.  i.e. treating FP add/mul as associative, when different temporaries mean it's really not.  This is totally unrelated to setting DAZ/FTZ).

---

Denormal is being used as a synonym for subnormal here: an FP value with the minimum exponent and a significand where the implicit leading bit is 0 instead of 1.  i.e. a value with magnitude small than [`FLT_MIN` or `DBL_MIN`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39746861/is-dbl-min-the-smallest-positive-double), the smallest representable *normalized* float/double.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number.

---

Instructions that produce a subnormal result can be *much* slower: to optimize for latency, the fast path in some hardware assumes normalized results, and takes a microcode assist if the result can't be normalized.  Use `perf stat -e fp_assist.any` to count such events.

**From Bruce Dawson's excellent series of FP articles: [That’s Not Normal–the Performance of Odd Floats](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/05/20/thats-not-normalthe-performance-of-odd-floats/)**.  Also:

- [Why does changing 0.1f to 0 slow down performance by 10x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314534/why-does-changing-0-1f-to-0-slow-down-performance-by-10x)
- [Avoiding denormal values in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487653/avoiding-denormal-values-in-c/2487733#2487733)

Agner Fog has done some testing (see his [microarch pdf](https://agner.org/optimize/)), and reports for Haswell/Broadwell:

> **Underflow and subnormals**
>
> Subnormal numbers occur when floating point operations are close to
> underflow. The handling of subnormal numbers is very costly in some
> cases because the subnormal results are handled by microcode
> exceptions.
>
> The Haswell and Broadwell have a penalty of approximately 124 clock
> cycles in all cases where an operation on normal numbers gives a
> subnormal result. There is a similar penalty for a multiplication
> between a normal and a subnormal number, regardless of whether the
> result is normal or subnormal. There is no penalty for adding a normal
> and a subnormal number, regardless of the result. There is no penalty
> for overflow, underflow, infinity or not- a-number results.
>
> The penalties for subnormal numbers are avoided if the "flush-to-zero"
> mode and the "denormals-are-zero" mode are both set in the MXCSR
> register.

So in some cases, modern Intel CPUs avoid penalties even with subnormals, but

Comment: can you explain why you say main stack frame is not heavily used... I assumed that all functions called from main(excluding async calls and launching new threads) use "main stack", so if they are aligned at 128B but main isnt they will not be aligned, because stack frames stacks :)

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: Yes they all use the primary call stack (unless you start new threads), but other function calls only maintain 16-byte alignment.  I haven't looked in detail at whether ICC's `main` actually has RSP 128-byte aligned when it makes a `call`, or if it just gets 128-byte alignment and then acts normally, reserving some multiple of 16 bytes below that.